# Velocity templates : how do I put the result of #springMessage() into a velocity variable

Tags: java, spring, velocity, template-engine

I have a value that comes out of this statement :

```
#springMessage("count.french")
```

That I need to append to another string like

```
#set ( $theCount = '5467 ' )
```

then essentially I need to do this

```
#set ( $countText = $theCount+#springMessage("count.french") )
```

but it doesn't like that.  Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there an error or log message?

Comment: @Dave  #set ( $countText = $theCount+#springMessage("count.french") )
gives this error (column 90 is where the '#' character is within the #set parens) --   
`ERROR [ContainerBase] Servlet.service() for servlet familytree threw exception
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "#springMessage" at list.vm[line 71, column 90]
Was expecting one of:
   "[" ...
   "{" ...
   "(" ...
   <WHITESPACE> ...
   <STRING_LITERAL> ...
   "true" ...
   "false" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "{" ...
    <LOGICAL_NOT> ...
`

Comment: Try just setting the macro result to a temp variable with another `#set` and using that in the string concatenation.

Comment: @DaveNewton like so?  #set ($test = #springMessage("blah"))  that was the first thing I tried actually -- and it didn't work either

Comment: @DaveNewton Velocity 1.6.4 and VelocityTools 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a temp variable should be as simple as the following (note the quotes):

```
#set ( $test = "#springMessage( $key )" )
```

Then, use this however you want, ex. concat it to another string.

Comment: I was actually just coming here to post the answer that I finally figured out.  Nice job.  Thanks.  Here's what I did in case anyone else is interested in how I used it : #set($var = $var+" #springMessage('some.property.name')")

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
#set($dynamicProp = '#set( $countText = $theCount ' + '#springMessage(count.french' + ' )')
#evaluate($dynamicProp)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me.  I'm glad to know about the evaluate function though.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem.  You'll want to avoid it if possible (the docs state you should use it only where necessary).  I wasn't quite sure if what you needed to do would allow for the simple case of the set function.